# j2me - Does RMS only save data when an application is executed via OTA?

Tags: java-me, ota, rms

I'm just starting to use RMS and I noticed that the **emulator** only keeps the data that was "supposedly" saved , if the application was executed via OTA.

[image]

If I run the application via **Regular Execution**, the data is only there while I'm using the application. Once I close it, all the data is gone.

Is that normal?? What exactly represents OTA?? Why are there some features that are only perceptible when the app is executed via OTA??

Thanks in advance.